# Code not to be used for firefox

Tags: html, firefox

```
html lang="{jrCore_lang module="_settings" id="lang" default="en"}" dir="{jrCore_lang module="_settings" id="direction" default="ltr"}" class="app js no-touch no-android chrome no-firefox no-iemobile no-ie no-ie8 no-ie10 no-ie11 no-ios no-ios7 ipad"
```

what happens is that i have there on the html tag the class "app" i don't want to be used for firefox (because it doesn't work there) but i want to use for other browsers. What shall be the work around?

The code is something like this:

```
.app,
  .app body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .app .hbox.stretch {
    height: 100%;
  }
  .app .vbox > section,
  .app .vbox > footer {
    position: absolute;
  }
  .app .vbox.flex > section > section {
    overflow: auto;
```

And it seems that the main problem comes from here:

```
  .vbox {
    display: table;
    border-spacing: 0;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .vbox > section,
  .vbox > footer {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .vbox > header ~ section {
    top: 50px;
  }
  .vbox > header.header-md ~ section {
    top: 60px;
  }
  .vbox > section.w-f {
    bottom: 50px;
  }
  .vbox > section.w-f-md {
    bottom: 60px;
  }
  .vbox > footer {
    top: auto;
    z-index: 1000;
  }
  .vbox.flex > header,
  .vbox.flex > section,
  .vbox.flex > footer {
    position: inherit;
  }
  .vbox.flex > section {
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .vbox.flex > section > section {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
  .ie .vbox.flex > section > section {
    display: table-cell;
  }
  .vbox.flex > section > section > section {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
```

Using that main absolute elements that should be at the top of the page go to the top and nothing shows on the page.

The page: http://dev.wowmusic.fm/

Thanks for any help.

[Update]
If i take away the display:table in

```
.vbox {
    display: table;
    border-spacing: 0;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

It seems to let the absolute positioning of the footer elements work (but i bet i need that display:table for something else).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your browser classes at the html level are set correctly, I think you'd just be able to do this:

```
.no-firefox .app,
  .no-firefox .app body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .no-firefox .app .hbox.stretch {
    height: 100%;
  }
  .no-firefox .app .vbox > section,
  .no-firefox .app .vbox > footer {
    position: absolute;
  }
  .no-firefox .app .vbox.flex > section > section {
    overflow: auto;
  }
```

I'd encourage you to look into why basic styling of some kind works for other browsers but not Firefox, but it's your choice.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll start looking for that